# Help on how to continue with code that verifies a registered user and updates mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

When a user registers, the script sends an email to verify his account. Clicking on the link, the script gets the token

```
$token = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["token"]);
```

and what I thought to do is

```
if($token != '') {
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET verified = '' WHERE verified = '$token'");
}
```

**or**

```
if($token != '') {
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET verified = '' WHERE verified = '$token'");
    if($result) { }
    else { }
}
```

What is my purpose is to echo a success or failed message on the user. When it will be success then the `verified` will be empty.

What is the appropriate way of doing this with my examples above?

Should I check if there is the token in the DB before updating it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current method updates a record if it exists but does not take into account that which does not exist or match. You should run something similar to:

```
if($token != '') {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members WHERE verified = '$token'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
       $records = $row[0];
    }

    if($records == 0) { echo 'no results'; }
    elseif($records ==1) { echo 'you matched'; then update the record. }
}
```

### edit

changed BACK to the while loop, wasn't thinking of the count returning 0 rows

Comment: @Nikolai - edited, I wasn't thinking on first edit, You can really go about it two ways, remove the COUNT(*), replace with some column or * and use mysql_num_rows call OR the method above. Above gives you ability to retrieve additional information like a userid based on the result of the token match.